# Get 'ui' in drop event attached to elements via .on() method in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get the element which was dragged and dropped in the drop event. I am attaching the drop event using .on() method. I am getting ui as undefined when the drop event is completed. Below is the code.

```
$(function() {
    var clientFrameWindow = $('#clientframe').get(0).contentWindow;
    $("#dragitemslistcontainer li").on('dragstart', function(event) {
        console.log("Drag Started");
    });
    $("#dragitemslistcontainer li").on('dragend', function() {
        console.log("Drag End");
    });
    $('#clientframe').load(function() {
        $(clientFrameWindow.document).find('body,html').on('drop', function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log('Drop event');
            console.log(ui); ** * //This prints undefined***
        });
    });
});
```

As 'ui' is undefined ui.draggable doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jquery-ui draggable widget, I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/avfd5j80/2/) which will log into console containing currently dragging item's id when dragging starts and ends from ui object. I've used `start: function(event, ui)` and `stop: function(event, ui)` events.

Comment: I added event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text","insertingHTML"); to the start function. I run into the error -  "Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined"

$(function() {
  $("#draggableCustom").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Drag started of item with id: " + ui.helper[0].id);
      event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text","insertingHTML");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("Drag ended of item with id: " + ui.helper[0].id);
    }
  });
});

Comment: what are you trying to say? is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/avfd5j80/2/) not working?

Comment: I added -event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text","insertingHTML"); to your start function. Now the js error out saying - Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined

Here is new jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/avfd5j80/4/

Comment: can you please elaborate what you're trying to achieve? on your question you stated that you wanted the ui object, but now, it seems you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will get 'ui' argument only in droppable or draggable function. Try something like this

```
$(".droppableArea").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      // your code
  }
});
```